# ¿Cómo hacer una pausa automática y una reproducción automática al pasar el mause en un vídeo de YouTube (iframe)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Buscando en internet encontré esto:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

  var player;

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   
    player = new YT.Player('player');

 }

 $(document).on('mouseover', '#player', function() {

   player.playVideo();

 });

 $(document).on('mouseout', '#player', function() {

   player.pauseVideo();

 });  

</script>
```

link: [Reproducir vídeo youtube solo cuando este este en el foco utilizando la YouTube API de IFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94819/reproducir-v%C3%ADdeo-youtube-solo-cuando-este-este-en-el-foco-utilizando-la-youtube)

Pero, no sé cómo lograr ese mismo efecto con varios vídeos de YouTube. Intenté combinarlo con esto:

```js
 var player;
  var player2;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: 'hdy78ehsjdi'
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: '81hdjskilct'
    });
  }
```

link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012886/loading-multiple-video-players-with-youtube-api

Sin embargo, no funciona. ¿Alguien podría por favor ayudarme a resolverlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de asignar cada "player" a una variable, creo un array con todos. De esa forma puedo utilizar los mismos eventos para todos los players.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="player1" class="player"></div>
<div id="player2" class="player"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var players = [];

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    players['player1'] = new YT.Player('player1', {
        videoId: 'x14LvDRJc0E'
    });
    players['player2'] = new YT.Player('player2', {
        videoId: '3fs9hRUTOnU'
    });
}

$(document).on('mouseover', '.player', function () {
    players[$(this).attr('id')].playVideo();
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.player', function () {
    players[$(this).attr('id')].pauseVideo();
});
```

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/azeos/4wuprjcL/) (no pude hacerlo andar desde el snippet).

Cada `<div>` tiene un ID con el que identificamos el player y una clase `.player` para poder identificarlos a todos.

Los eventos se los asociamos a `.player` y como el ID es igual a la clave que usamos para el array, podemos manipular el player que corresponda.

Tené en cuenta que el primer parámetro de `YT.Player()` es el ID de un elemento, en este caso un `<div>`.